# Dice roll. DND, add numbers from an array together

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, dice

So i created a basic dice rolling dicord bot for Dungeons & Dragons.

the code i have so far works to roll any type of dice, (ex. "roll xdy" "roll 1d20", "roll 100d100")

when someone sends a message that matches, it will output the resulting dice rolls.

my issue is that i would like to add these numbers together and show the resulting total aswell but im unsure how to get there.

```
// Run dotenv
require('dotenv').config();

const { any } = require('async');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });


client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
        z = msg.content;
        matches = z.match(/\d+/g);
        x = matches[0];
        y = matches[1];

    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
        msg.reply('pong');
    }
    if (msg.content == 'roll ' + x + 'd' + y) {
        
        function rollDie(sides) {
            if (!sides) sides = 6;
            return 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * sides);
        }

        function rollDice(number, sides) {
            var total = [];
            var number = x;
            var sides = y;
            while (number-- > 0) total.push(rollDie(sides));
            return total;
        }
        msg.reply("result: " + rollDice());
        console.log(rollDice())
    }
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemed like you were declaring variables without using `let` or `var` (`z`, `matches`, `x`, and `y`). No reason to use `var` anymore. You had parameters for the `rollDice` function but then were just pulling from the variables you created and not using the parameters, so I modified that. I used the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to sum the array. I changed some variable names to be more descriptive (such as `z` to `msgContent`) and used them in more available places.

In your `rollDie` function you give a default die side number of 6, but because of the `if` statement wrapping it, the only way the function will be called is if a side number is specifically chosen. So I modified this so that someone can type "Roll 3" if they just want to roll 3 6-sided dice. When reporting the dice roll I used the [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method so they would display in a comma and space separated list instead of as an array.

---

**I have modified this solution after seeing your edits.** `msgContent` is now created at the top with a new regular expression I made that is robust enough to get rid of the toLowerCase and trim method input scrubbing as well as the other string checks previously necessary in the code. The `msg` will pass the [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) [test method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) if `msg` is either 'roll #' or 'roll #d#' (where '#' is any numbers besides 0 of any digit length). The regular expression will automatically ignore character case and any whitespace on the ends of the string. I converted the `rollDie` function into a more succinct arrow function and put it inside the `rollDice` function scope because that is the only place it needs to be called. You don't need to write `if (!sides) sides = 6;` because you can just use the expression `(sides || 6)` because `sides` is only used once and if is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) that expression will just evaluate as 6.  I also stopped declaring `diceResults` as a blank array, as it can be defined later when the output of `rollDice()` is saved to it.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { any } = require("async");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });

client.on("messageCreate", (msg) => {
  const msgContent = msg.content,
        msgRegEx = /\s*roll\s[1-9]\d*(d[1-9]\d*)?\s*/i;

  if (msgRegEx.test(msgContent)) {
    let matches = msgContent.match(/\d+/g),
        numDice = matches[0],
        numSides = matches[1],
        diceResults;

    function rollDice(number, sides) {
      const rollDie = sides => Math.floor(Math.random() * (sides || 6)) + 1;

      let diceArray = [];

      while (number-- > 0) diceArray.push(rollDie(sides));

      return diceArray;
    }

    function calcDiceTotal(diceArray) {
      return diceArray.reduce(
        (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue,
        0
      );
    }

    diceResults = rollDice(numDice, numSides);

    msg.reply(
      "ROLLING... " + diceResults.join(", ") +
      " || TOTAL: " + calcDiceTotal(diceResults)
    );
  }
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Output should look like this: `"ROLLING... 3, 1, 6, 3, 5 || TOTAL: 18"`

Comment: thank you i was able to take the code you provided and learned some things along the way.
i made a few changes to stop the bot from breaking everytime someone sends a message other than "roll" but managed to get it all working thanks to your fixes.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I was going to edit and add some more potential input error conditions to keep it from breaking, but I figured that went far beyond the scope of the question. Happy you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it.

Reduce applies a callback function to each element of a given array, so you can use it to add up all the values of an array and report it.

passing an array 'totalArr' into this function should give you the sum total of all numbers in the array

Javascript

```
const rollTotal = function (totalArr) {
const startingRoll = 0;
const subTotal = totalArr.reduce(
(previousValue, currentValue) => 
 previousValue + currentValue,
startingRoll
);
return subTotal;
};
```

Test

```
console.log(rollTotal([1, 2, 3]));
```

Output = 6

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final bot code which works as intended, used the fixes from above and tweaked it so the bot didnt break when someone typed any other messages.

seems to work pretty well!

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { any } = require("async");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });

client.on("messageCreate", (msg) => {

  if (msg.content.startsWith('roll ')) {
    let msgContent = msg.content.trim().toLowerCase(),
        matches = msgContent.match(/\d+/g),
        numDice = matches[0],
        numSides = matches[1],
        diceResults = [];

    if (
      msgContent === "roll " + numDice ||
      msgContent === "roll " + numDice + "d" + numSides
    ) {
      function rollDie(sides) {
        if (!sides) sides = 6;

        return 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * sides);
      }

      function rollDice(number, sides) {
        let diceArray = [];

        while (number-- > 0) diceArray.push(rollDie(sides));

        return diceArray;
      }

      function calcDiceTotal(diceArray) {
        return diceArray.reduce(
          (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue,
          0
        );
      }

      diceResults = rollDice(numDice, numSides);

      msg.reply(
        "ROLLING... " + diceResults.join(", ") +
        " || TOTAL: " + calcDiceTotal(diceResults)
      );
    }
  }
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Comment: Well done. 1 issue I see is that the input scrubbing performed by the trim() and toLowerCase() functions are now of limited usefulness because you are checking msg content in the if statement before those methods are invoked. I have modified my solution for you and added a robust regular expression that will check the input in a better way, doing away with all other needed input scrubbing and testing. I hope you'll check it out.